# Catching and handling all exceptions in my own class

Tags: c++, class, exception

Hello to all and sorry for my english!

How can I do the title above?

For example, I have a class contains a some functions that can throw exceptions:

```
class cl {
public:
    void f1();
    void f2();
};

void cl::f1()
{
    // throw exception
}

void cl::f2()
{
    // throw exception
}
```

I need to handle them.

Are there any other method to handle exceptions (that throws in my class) in one place of the code except code like this:

```
void cl::f1()
{   
    try
    {
        // throw exception
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        // handling
    }
 }

void cl::f1()
{   
    try
    {
        // throw exception
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        // handling
    }
 }
```

or this:

```
int main()
{
    cl c;
    try
    {
        f1();
        f2();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        // handling
    }
}
```

?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: AFAIK, you have to go with one of mentioned ways. If you really want a centralized feeling, probably you can call a dedicated function for handling exceptions in `catch` block. But why do you need this? Are you trying to use exceptions for control flow?

Comment: @Xiangyan I am writing a class to work with file io (using fstream class). I want to catch io errors using exceptions (I set exceptions mask with std::ios::exceptions) and handle it in one place of code.

Comment: In the first case exception is part of your class implementation, client doesn't know anything about this. In the second case exception is part of the class public interface. Different approaches, used for different purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any other method to handle exceptions (that throws in my
>   class) in one place of the code except code like this:

In my opinion you would typically only handle an exception when:

- You can remedy it i.e do something about it e.g allow the user to select a different file.
- You can add additional information.

For the latter case, it would mean throwing a new exception (possible of different type) from the handler.

If neither of the above hold, let it propagate to a level where it can be handled. In your case, I would not have a try/catch within f1 and f2, but only at the callsite (in main).

You might ask whether one cannot(should not) do certain cleanup work in the catch handler. I personally have never found this to be necessary if/when one uses the stack/scope to clean up [see RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII). I/we usually have one catch handler per thread at the highest level, and this simply performs logging. We catch (and use exceptions) for runtime errors mostly. For logic errors we use assert (even in release mode), but this can be (and have been) debated often.